# Distance Formula showing "Resource leak: 'scan' is never closed"

Tags: java, resource-leak

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//distance = square root of [(x2-x1)squared + (y2-y1)squared + (z2-z1)squared]

public class FirstCode
{
    static double distance(double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2)
    {
        return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (z2-z1)*(z2-z1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        double x2, x1, y2, y1, z2, z1;
        double distance;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the x coordinate for point 1: ");
        x1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the y coordinate for point 1: ");
        y1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the x coordinate for point 2: ");
        x2 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the y coordinate for point 2: ");
        y2 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the z coordinate for point 3: ");
        z1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the z coordinate for point 3: ");
        z2 = scan.nextDouble();
        distance = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2,z1,z2);
        System.out.println("The distance between the two points is " + distance + " .");
    }
}
```

Comment: Coordinates (x1,y1,z1) = (15.34, 1.15, 0.19), (x2,y2,z2) = (-15.34, 1.15, 0.19)   Answer is 30.69 but the java code above showing 15.34?

Comment: I rolled back all your changes since the very first version. There was an answer to that, so you're not allowed to drastically change the question into a new one. Create a new post, if you have a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the Scanner at the end.

```
scan.close();
```